# Tesco Hudl Hardware Problem = bin?

Tags: crashes

My boy has a Tesco Hudl 1 - been trying to stop it crashing that is was doing very regularly.

Did a full system reset with power on/vol up and reformat.   On restarting after this with completely clean system it glitches again.    Sometimes not even getting past the boot logo.

My feeling is something wrong on the hardware side, and this thing is destined for the bin.   Bad RAM?

Any Android specialists out there like to confirm fears?

Answer (score 1):

I contacted the ebay vendor who sold me the hudl.  He recommended full charge and reset button again.

It boots now at least.  Will try to install just one or two apps and see if its a software issue, and download any updates.  Hope this helps someone in the future.